# SQL Server Query: Get a List of Columns Which Don't Exist in Another Table's Field

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to select all the columns *names only* from a SPLANNING_ROOMDATA2 table in such way that those names should not exist in a comma separated list of column names in another table. Here is my query in a C# ASP.NET application. My query generates an error like '`syntax error near Where`'.

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Splanning_RoomData2' where COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT ATTRIBUTENAME FROM SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES)", con);//get only column names
```

Note, if I remove the second `Where` clause then I do get a list of columns but that is not what I desire. I have done some searches but none met my needs.

***Edit: As of now, none of the answers are working. I am going to try to change the splanning_restricted_attributes table's to allow one restricted attributed per row--instead of comma separated one. Thanks all. **

Comment: You have put the `where` keyword 2 times.Try as `where TABLE_NAME='Splanning_RoomData2'  and COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT ATTRIBUTENAME FROM SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES)`

Comment: let me try to remove that. thanks

Comment: I think yours will work; please put an answer. thx!

Comment: if the your table row is comma separated then you need to take look at @Gordon Linoff answer as directly `IN` can not operate on it.

Comment: I don't think any of the two answers are working. I could use xml, instead of comma separated list of column names inside the attributename table if that helps but these will be hard coded values and csv would be easier to read.

Comment: There are other ways to get what you want if you search `split the comma separated list` . [Here is blog](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: But even Gordon's Answer doesn't work--please see the Comments there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AND instead of WHERE twice

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Splanning_RoomData2' 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT ATTRIBUTENAME 
                        FROM SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES)", con);
```

Comment: `IN` doesn't work for a list stored as a comma-separated value in a single column.

Comment: I am checking this to see if indeed all data is being returned as needed. Thanks.

Comment: is attributename a CSV?

Comment: @Matt's answer worked because I changed the SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES table to remove the csv values per row and instead put them as one value per row. This makes for a bit longer set of data but not too bad. None of the other Answers worked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

You should not store lists as comma separated values.  They should be in a separate table, called a junction table with one row per column and table.

Sometimes, though, you are stuck with such a structure.  Here is one method for getting what you need:

```
select c.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c LEFT JOIN
     SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES ra
     ON ',' + lower(ra.ATTRIBUTENAME) + ',' LIKE '%,' + lower(c.column_name) + ',%'
where TABLE_NAME = 'Splanning_RoomData2' and ra.ATTRIBUTENAME is null;
```

Comment: Yes, the first person's answer is still returning the values; going to try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting an error: Ambiguous column name 'TABLE_NAME' using your Anwer.

Comment: I don't think this answer is going to work--please see my comment above.

Comment: @Meengla Just use an appropriate table [alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) with the column name. If I am not mistaken, then change the WHERE clause to the `where  c.TABLE_NAME = 'Splanning_RoomData2';`

Comment: The error went away when I did c.TABLE_NAME but still the results are not expected: I am still getting the names of columns from the Splanning_Restricted_Attributes table's Attributename field.

Comment: And looks like Gordon's answer is doing exactly what opposite of what is needed?!

Comment: @Meengla In such a case use a 'NOT LIKE' statement : `ON ',' + lower(ra.ATTRIBUTENAME) + ',' NOT LIKE '%,' + lower(c.column_name) + ',%'`

Comment: @EugenePodskal: I think Code of Coder's answer has your suggestion and please see my Comment to that. Still doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am just posting the updated answer of @Gordon Linoff answer try the query as,

```
select c.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c JOIN
     SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES ra
     ON ',' + lower(ra.ATTRIBUTENAME) + ',' NOT LIKE '%,' + lower(c.column_name) + ',%'
where c.TABLE_NAME = 'Splanning_RoomData2';
```

Comment: trying...but you may need to make c.TABLE_NAME?

Comment: Okay, I tried your code (with c.TABLE_NAME) and it now returns multiple entries for each column name and also still returns the unwanted values.

Comment: BTW, instead of using the 'LIKE' operator can't we use the equality one in this case? The column names and the values from CSV are being converted to lowercase here.

Comment: As you can see from the Edited question: I am changing the table structure. Thanks for the help!