# SQL to Return Matched Records from Two Tables in a Certain Way

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This question is built upon my earlier question, which may be seen at:

[SQL Server Query: Get a List of Columns Which Don't Exist in Another Table's Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985853/sql-server-query-get-a-list-of-columns-which-dont-exist-in-another-tables-fie)

I have the following data in the splanning_restricted_attributes table

groupid 1 =  `RoomArea,Disability,Shower` (**edit** not CSV; one per/row**)

groupid 3 =  `Water,Shower`(**edit not CSV; one per row**)

And my updated query is:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='Splanning_RoomData2' 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN  
    (
        SELECT ATTRIBUTENAME 
        FROM SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES 
        where groupid != @session_groupid
    )
```

This query kind of works except I had not factored in what would happen when two (or more) groups were allowed access to the same attributes. As executed, this query returns only `RoomArea,Disability` when session `groupid` is 1 and only water when session groupid is 3.

How can I modify so that if groupid is 1 or 3 then it should return `Shower` along with other attributes?

Thanks!

*** Edit*** The query should return appropriate values when session groupid is either 1 or 3. So if groupid is 1 then return: `RoomArea,Disability,Shower` ; if groupid is 3 then return `Water,Shower`

*** Edit 2: DDL and some more info below***

```
[SPLANNING_ROOMDATA2]
[RoomArea] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[Disability] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[Shower] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
[Water] [nvarchar](254) NULL,


[splanning_restricted_attributes]
[attributename] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[groupid] [int] NOT NULL,

[splanning_groups]
[groupid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[groupname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

So both `SPLANNING_ROOMDATA2` and `splanning_groups` tables will have representation in the `splanning_restricted_attributes` table in such a way that each row of the `splanning_restricted_attributes`will have a groupid and one `attributename` per row.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The query should return appropriate values when session groupid is either 1 or 3. So if groupid is 1 then return: RoomArea,Disability,Shower  ; if groupid is 3 then return Water,Shower

Comment: I am sure this is perfectly clear to you but with no information about this table we can't help a lot. Give us something to work with.

Comment: Okay, let me try again. I just did edit this question a bit ago. Also, I had the schema in the other question.

Comment: Show the ddl and some of this other table please. Do you have delimited values in that table? This query is probably fairly straight forward but with no details it is impossible.

Comment: Working on a brief DDL for all the three tables; no CSVs: Each row in the restricted table has one attribute

Comment: Okay, second edit done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I ended up doing a UNION query:

```
cmd.CommandText = 
@"select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
TABLE_NAME='Splanning_RoomData2' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN 
   (SELECT ATTRIBUTENAME FROM SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES) 
   UNION (SELECT ATTRIBUTENAME FROM SPLANNING_RESTRICTED_ATTRIBUTES 
   where    groupid = @session_groupid)";
```

And I think the results are as expected. Phew!